# Execute Shell Commands from Program running in WINE

Tags: linux, shell, wine

I have a windows program running on Linux using WINE.

How can I call Linux shell commands from the windows program?

Comment: What is that Windows program ?

Comment: What happens if you use the windows APIs for executing a process, but give as target a linux executable via whatever drive letter maps to that filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit: user1182474's comment is correct; Wine doesn't isolate the programs it runs. (It tries to hide it, but not very thoroughly.) I totally failed at using Google. Psen's comment below is more correct, and references the FAQ. (Note that, for that to work, you may need to have the program's directory available through a Wine drive mapping. Or, see Anonymous Replier's answer.)*

== Old Answer ==

Wine isolates the programs it runs. The applications are, if all works as intended, presented with an environment indistinguishable from Windows. Unfortunately for your purposes, that means that you can't access the features of the host OS (Linux). I mean, you could patch Wine to do that, but I get the impression that it would be more work than it's worth.

There is hope! Cygwin is a Unix-like environment for Windows. You could install Cygwin in Wine, and use Cygwin to run your shell script. (Apparently, installing with 'winetricks cygwin' is easiest) Invoke Cygwin's bash shell (inside some Wine program) like this:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash  myscript
```

Of course, change c:\cygwin to wherever you install it.

Comment: Wine does not isolate the programs it runs at all... I would downvote this if I could.

Comment: @user1182474 Wow, what an oversight. You're right. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 14):

With newer Wine versions *(tested with Wine 1.7.38)*, you can run a Linux program from within Wine in the following way (here to launch gedit, as an example):

```
wineconsole cmd
```

...and from that wine console:

```
start /unix /usr/bin/gedit
```

If you want to launch a Linux program directly from within a Windows-application, the following line did work for me:

```
cmd /c start /unix /usr/bin/gedit
```

To test this, you can call directly on your Linux console this:

```
wine cmd /c start /unix /usr/bin/gedit
```

*One important thing to Note: the program you want to start needs to have the executable bit set, otherwise calling it from Wine will fail!*

Comment: This works for ui applications, but I can't seem to get it to work with any command-line ones - i.e. ffmpeg, git, etc.  It doesn't show an error, nor any output.  Just nothing.  Has anyone else had any luck?

Answer (score 10):

Try this (runs Gnome calculator on my Linux Mint system):

```
wineconsole cmd
```

...and from the wine console:

```
/bin/sh gcalctool
```

On this general principle, you can also open documents and associate files with a linux app by editing the wine registry. There is a section about it in the wine FAQ:

[6.6.3 How do I associate a native program with a file type in Wine?](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_associate_a_native_program_with_a_file_type_in_Wine.3F)

So you should be able to write shell scripts and call them OK.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, just get `Can't recognize /bin/sh as an internal or external command, or batch script.`

Comment: It works fine now, except for a DDE error that seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 4):

Try (where yourprogram is the linux/unix program you want to execute in wine)

```
ln -s /path/to/yourprogram /path/to/wineprefix/drive_c/windows/system32/yourprogram
```

That is how I have gotten java working.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for some (?) command-line applications - i.e. ffmpeg, git, etc.  It doesn't show an error, nor any output.  Just nothing.  Are you seeing different?

Answer (score 4):

How to call a Linux program from a Wine program — five points in terms of API.

#### 1. Proper `PATHEXT`

In the new Wine versions (since 2.0.1 at least) it is need to add **empty** extension (i.e. just dot character: `.`) into the list of executable file extensions in `PATHEXT` environment variable. Without this addition an error message can say something like:

`Can't recognize '/bin/bash' as an internal or external command, or batch script.`

To fix the initial `PATHEXT` value in the registry the following commands snippet can be used (for each `WINEPREFIX`):

```
k='HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'
pathext_orig=$( wine reg query "$k" /v PATHEXT | tr -d '\r' | awk '/^  /{ print $3 }' )
echo "$pathext_orig" | grep -qE '(^|;)\.(;|$)' \
  || wine reg add "$k" /v PATHEXT /f /d "${pathext_orig};."
```

This code checks and then modifies `PATHEXT` if it doesn't contain `.` item only.

See also: [How do I launch native applications from a Windows application?](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_launch_native_applications_from_a_Windows_application.3F) in WineHQ FAQ; **NB**:

> Note that this change will have to be made every time you upgrade
>   Wine, as it will be reverted whenever the wineprefix is updated.

#### 2. Path to executable

It is likely that by default you will need to specify the full (or relative) path to an executable file (for example, `/bin/bash`), since a Wine process doesn't inherit `PATH` environment variable from the parent Linux process.
Note that the current drive in a Wine process is mapped to the Linux root folder by default, so no need to specify a drive letter. I.e. `/bin/bash` just works, but not `bash`.

Another way is to alter `PATH` environment variable in Wine accordingly, or to change the current directory.

Whenever a path contains non-ASCII characters — as argument of `CreateProcessA` — the path should be in Wine locale and according to `LANG` environment variable; see also the [answer by Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004070/execute-shell-commands-from-program-running-in-wine#answer-23524073) in this topic, and a forum post how to [set encoding to use with non-Unicode application in Wine](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=18095). For `CreateProcessW` the path should be in UTF-16 in any case.

#### 3. Executable format

Linux executables in shared object format cannot be executed from Wine. See: [Executables vs Shared objects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690631/executables-vs-shared-objects) and [How to execute shell scripts from 32-bit Wine on 64-bit Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296093/how-to-execute-shell-scripts-from-32-bit-wine-on-64-bit-linux). For example, `/bin/dash` can be "ELF 64-bit LSB shared object" (see output of `file /bin/dash`) and cannot be executed from Wine in such case. Error message says:

```
wine: Bad EXE format for Z:\bin\dash..
Can't recognize '/bin/dash' as an internal or external command, or batch script.
```

#### 4. No waiting

A parent Wine process cannot wait (for example, via `WaitForSingleObject`) on a child Linux process since it isn't provided with the child process handle — it is just 0. See bugreport: [CreateProcess doesn't set hProcess correctly when starting a Linux program](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18335) (Status: CLOSED WONTFIX).

Nevertheless a parent process can indirectly wait a child process via blocking read on the certain pipe if the child process uses stdout (see also bellow).

#### 5. Difference in pipes redirection

Perhaps it is a bug in Wine, but a parent process should close the std handles, that are passed into CreateProcess, only after close the own handles (or just before it) for the corresponding pipes. While in Windows these handles can be closed just after `CreateProcess` function is completed. By MSDN these handles may be closed at once after passing (see [CreateProcess function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)):

> Handles in STARTUPINFO or STARTUPINFOEX must be closed with
>   CloseHandle when they are no longer needed.

In Wine 2.0.1, the corresponding pipe in a child Linux process will be closed immediately in such case, and the child process will **prematurely stop**. But not in the case of a child Windows process.

Comment: I haven't been able to get any command-line Linux applications to run from Wine (i.e. ffmpeg, git, etc) - it doesn't show an error, nor any output.  Just nothing.  I'm guessing this might be related to your 5th point: the pipe in a child Linux process will be closed immediately, and the child process will prematurely stop.  Is there no workaround for this - ie. some way I could invoke Linux ffmpeg from WINE?

Comment: @Metal450, when you run a Linux cli-application from the Wine command line (e.g. `cmd.exe`), it is `cmd.exe` who handles the pipes, and it handles them properly (at least in Wine 2.0.1). Point 5 is about the case when you run a Linux application using Windows API (i.e. CreateProcess function) and should handle the pipes by yourself.

Comment: From cmd.exe, are you able to get any output from i.e. `start /unix /usr/bin/git` or `start /unix /usr/bin/ffmpeg`?

Comment: Try `/bin/ls`.  Don't use `start`, it is not suitable to run a Linux command (i.e. cli-application). If you need to start a command in a new window, use `cmd` wrapper, e.g.: `start cmd /k /bin/ls`

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand that answer.  I'm trying specifically to invoke ffmpeg from WINE - as an initial proof of concept I was trying to run it from cmd, but was unable to see any output. You said not to use `start`, but isn't `start /unix` the given way to run a Linux command? Wasn't that the original poster's question?

Comment: (To be even more specific, I'm trying to figure out how to get FFmpeg Batch AV Converter - https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-batch/ - to be able to invoke the Linux native version of ffmpeg.  The UI works great in WINE, and it *can* invoke the Windows version of ffmpeg, but it's considerably slower.  It's open-source, & the dev - who isn't me - has worked to get it running under WINE. However, I use it a lot & am trying to help him figure out how to do this last piece of the puzzle.)

Comment: @Metal450: Were you ever able to get this working?  I'm trying to do something similar and see a lot of comments from you on different questions I'm coming across looking for information about this.

Comment: Nope, never did.  Please let me know if you do.

Comment: @Metal450, @BrenBarn, I [was wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004070/execute-shell-commands-from-program-running-in-wine#comment110774890_45545068) that `cmd.exe` can properly run and wait a Linux program. I have created a [small program](https://github.com/ruv/wine-runio) that can help to run Linux programs from WineHQ. You might want to [test it](https://github.com/ruv/wine-runio/releases). Comment [in GitHub](https://github.com/ruv/wine-runio/issues) please, if any.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working for me - will post a follow-up on your github.

Comment: @ruvim: I also couldn't figure out how to use your tool.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
Z:\bin\ls
```

But maybe you are looking rather for something like http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ that you will install into your wine "windows"? Or the already mentioned cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

for me the first solution I found [on this site](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-bc5b677c29daa2cd16b83bca8c88f31b2341cb98) worked - associating an extension with winebrowser, and default gnome file viewer launches from wine when clicking on a file in wine explorer (or in other windows applications).

Previous **solution with shell scripts**, which worked in wine 1.4, **does not work with wine 1.6**.

However, the problem I noticed is that names in Windows encoding are not converted to Linux locale, preventing this to work with e.g. Russian directory names

Answer (score 0):

The shell script that was [listed on WineHQ FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-bc5b677c29daa2cd16b83bca8c88f31b2341cb98) can be slightly modified, eg like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
WFILE=$(echo -E $2)
FILE=$(wine winepath $WFILE)
$1 $FILE
```

The rest works just as described in the FAQ.

Comment: I haven't been able to get any of these methods to work under current (1.8/1.9) Wine running under OS X. I can get the wineconsole to open, but I'm trying to find some way to run (for example) the OS X Calculator. This does NOT work: `cmd /c start /unix open /Applications/Calculator.app` (or any other command that works in the OS X Terminal). Does anyone have any up-to-date information, please?

Comment: @emendelson /Applications/Calculator.app is a folder the real app lies inside /Application/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS .You can explore the contents by opening a console and entering “ls /Application/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS” there.

Answer (score 0):

I love the [Far Commander](http://www.farmanager.com/), which does run under **wine**, so I set up these two scripts:

1. To launch Linux applications from windows

C:\windows\xt.bat

```
start /unix /usr/bin/xterm -e %*
```

2. To open files in Linux from the wine environment (Far):

C:\windows\xdg.bat

```
cd >C:\windows\command\mypwd
start /unix /etc/init.d/winopen.sh  %*
```

/etc/init.d/winopen.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
PWDF=`winepath -u 'C:\windows\command\mypwd'`
fromdos $PWDF
xdg-open $(winepath -u $(cat $PWDF)/$1)
```

Now I can type on the Far command line:

> xt top
>
> xdg SomeDocument.PDF

and get results in the Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSH if you need to wait for the command to complete and get it's output. Otherwise (if you need only to start it) any of these methods will work:

- [File type association](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_associate_a_native_program_with_a_file_type_in_Wine.3F)
- [start /unix](https://wiki.winehq.org/Start)
- [wine cmd /c](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_launch_native_applications_from_a_Windows_application.3F)
- CreateProcess

The core problem is that CreateProcess returns [zero PID and handle](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18335), so you can't wait for the child process completion and get it's exit code.

I've also tried [standard pipes redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) with no luck. The output of Linux child process is lost, pipes are empty.

So, with CreateProcess and friends you have to use some kind of [trigger files](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=23674), which looks not too beautiful. Like I said, we're going to use SSH instead.

Comment: How exactly do you "use SSH" to get the program's output?

Comment: PLINK.EXE -i <private key.ppk> -no-antispoof <user>@localhost <command>