# How to execute shell scripts from 32-bit Wine on 64-bit Linux?

Tags: linux, sh, 32bit-64bit, wine, ubuntu-14.04

My 32-bit application is running under Wine, and to help it better integrate with the environment, it runs some shell scripts.  I was just testing under Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, and my program crashed with this error:

```
err:process:create_process starting 64-bit process L"Z:\\bin\\sh" not supported in 32-bit wineprefix
```

I've tried searching for a 32-bit build of "sh" on my system, but couldn't find one.  Any creative ideas on how I can get past this issue?

Comment: I would just install a 32 bits shell (and some other essential utilities), perhaps an `schroot`-ed minimal distribution (see `debootstrap`)

Comment: You're using `winelib` to build a Linux program with emulated Win32 API, or running a Win32 executable in PE format under Wine?  The first would be a programming question, the second is more of a power user question about configuring software you didn't develop (Wine).

Comment: I'm the developer, but it's not using winelib.  The application is aware of when it's on Linux/Mac (via Wine) and utilizes shell scripts to better integrate with the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a user of the program in question and I did some experimenting with it.

### Not 32-bit vs. 64-bit but "shared object" vs. "executable" ?

Running `file /bin/dash` it prints:

```
/bin/dash: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), ...
```

Running `file /bin/bash` however prints:

```
/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), ...
```

`dash` is a "shared object" while `bash` is an "executable". Clearly `/bin/dash` seems to work like an executable in some way (I don't know the technical details here), but it seems that this difference matters to Wine.

I got the same error as you reported (can't start 64 bit process) for Wine 1.4, but the error I got on newer versions of Wine was `wine: Bad EXE format for Z:\bin\sh..`

If you actually just replace `/bin/sh` with `/bin/bash` (even though that's a 64-bit binary) it will work. Wine also didn't seem to like running a symlink, but copying over `/bin/bash` worked.

So first back up the existing (symlinked) `/bin/sh` with:

```
sudo cp /bin/sh /bin/sh_orig
```

Then copy `bash` to `sh`:

```
sudo cp /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Then when I ran Wine with the program and its calls to `/bin/sh` work fine.

### Alternatively, you download a 32-bit shell directly

Pull down the .deb file for the 32-bit bash shell:

```
 wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bash/bash_4.3-6ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

I your home directory, extract it into a folder:

```
mkdir ~/bash_4.3-6ubuntu1_i386
dpkg -x bash_4.3-6ubuntu1_i386.deb ~/bash_4.3-6ubuntu1_i386
```

Copy the bash script into /bin/sh:

```
sudo mv /bin/sh /bin/sh64original
sudo cp ~/bash_4.3-6ubuntu1_i386/bin/bash /bin/sh
sudo chown root:root /bin/sh
```

### Or run `schroot`, but still must copy /bin/bash to /bin/sh

Basile Starynkevitch mentioned above about setting up a 32-bit shell in an `schroot` environment. I did that with an Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit environment and ran into the same issue with the `dash` vs. `bash` "shared object" vs. "executable" (but when I copied `/bin/bash` to `/bin/sh` it worked), so that helped me realize that the distinction wasn't the 32-bit vs. 64-bit difference but the format of the shell executables that mattered to Wine.

If you would like I can post details for setting up the `schroot` evnironment but basically I followed the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot but needed to configure the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to have the full list of packages (as are installed in my default host system) for `apt-get install wine` to work.

Comment: So maybe if my app just called /bin/bash in place of /bin/sh things will "just work" without any intervention on the user.  I'll have to explore this idea!  I'll report back with what I find!

Comment: I updated my application to call /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh and now it works great on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit + Wine.  (And it still works great on Mac OS X 10.6-10.9 + Wine).  Thanks for your help on this!