# Call R (recompiled and in native Linux) from Wine

Tags: r, wine

I have recompiled R for the Intel MKl library and it sits in my linux o/s - it needs to be in linux to enable me to work with the xeon phi easily.

On the other side, I have some some code that is running in Wine. This code needs to run in Wine as that particular program doesnt have a Linux build.

**The aim**: This code in Wine needs to call the equivalent of `Rterm.exe` from the native recompiled R sitting in linux.

**What I have tried and problems**: I have tried to call it using `cmd`, however it seems to not open an interactive session of R - it opens and closes R and so I am unable to work with the linux native R session from Wine.

Will appreciate any help/direction anyone can provide

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can open an interactive session of R in UNIX using the `--interactive` parameter, [here you have the help](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Invoking-R).

Another option is to do differents calls using `--save` and`--restore`, so each execution continues where the previous one ended, and you only have to clean the `.RData` file when you log out.

I'm not sure if it's something like that what you're looking for but I hope this can help you.

Comment: thanks Juan - I was following the last example (relating to Far Commander) in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004070/execute-shell-commands-from-program-running-in-wine...can you tell me where I would include the --interactive parameter? Shall I edit the batch file?